# How to extend a Generic Collection in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, generics, collections

I have a Generic collection like this:

```
TFoo = class;

TFooCollection<T: TFoo> = class(TObjectDictionary<string, T>)
   procedure DoSomething;
end;
```

It works fine.

Now I need to extend **TFooCollection** like this:

```
TBar = class( TFoo );   

TBarCollection<T: TBar> = class(TFooCollection)
   procedure DoSomethingElse;
end;
```

And the compiler complains that TFooCollection isn't defined.
As TBar is inheriting from TFoo, I would like to take advantage of TFooCollection methods (that would work with TFoo and TBar items) and do something else just with TBar Collections.

Is it possible in Delphi?

Comment: As a broad rule prefer encapsulation to inheritance. Do you really want every method of the collection class to be exposed by your class?

Comment: @david It's just that in the base class collection I have some logic regarding saving/loading. The inheritance tree is not deep (just one level) but it is very broad as we have lots of collections with different item classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You knew how to extend the generic collection `TObjectDictionary`, so simply apply that same technique when extending the generic collection `TFooCollection`. `TObjectDictionary` doesn't specify a type by itself — you needed to provide values for its two generic type parameters. One you hard-coded to `string`, and the other you provided by forwarding the generic type parameter received in `TFooCollection`.

Likewise, when specifying the base type for `TBarCollection`, you can either provide a hard-coded value for the `TFooCollection` type parameter, or you can forward the parameter from `TBarCollection`. You probably want to do the latter:

```
type
  TBarCollection<T: TBar> = class(TFooCollection<T>)
  end;
```

Comment: It's exactly what I want! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remember that in generic classes, the type declarations are part of the type name.
The compiler is quite correct is stating that you do not have a TFooCollection type defined.  You have defined a type called TFooCollection (or TFooCollection).